# Socket.io Deployment

Tags: deployment, socket.io, next.js13

I have made a project in which I have used socket.io to chat with someone in realtime.
I have used pages router in Next JS. How and where can I deploy my project for free?
I tried deploying that on vercel, but then I got to know that vercel does not support socket.io.

If there is any other way I can make realtime chat application without socket.io and realtime database, just let me know.

In a nutshell:
I made a realtime chat application using socket.io and next js pages router but I am not able to deploy that web application. Vercel does not support socket.io. Heroku is not free for deploying web applications. I need a good website through which I can deploy my socket.io project.